# A "reasonable" security model for Android app and REST

Tags: android, rest, security, encryption

We are getting started with developing an android app and the corresponding REST APIs and I need to figure out a security model for the same. I've close to zero experience with designing secure systems and would like some expert opinion on the loopholes of a first draft we've come up with.

I've been all over the web for the past few days and everyone seems to suggest HTTPS and OAUTH as the proven answer. Since our app doesn't deal with anyone's bank account, I think we can live with less than DoD grade security (although even they get hacked often!). And we don't want to spend the effort for OAUTH unless there really is no other reasonable alternative.

We're trying to avoid HTTPS because the app will, at times, be polling the server every few seconds and we thought it'd be too expensive to use it for all REST calls. Also, the payload for some of those API calls can be too big (2-4 KBytes) for asymmetric encryption.

Here's what we've lined up so far:

1. User creates an account by entering a unique 'username' and a 'password' on the registration page in the app
2. The 'username' is stored in plaintext in SharedPreferences using MODE_PRIVATE
3. The SHA-256 of the 'password' is also stored in SharedPreferences using MODE_PRIVATE
4. The user credentials ('username' and hashed 'password') are sent to the server using https://
5. The server creates an authentication "token" (a random AES key, really, using a CSPRNG), stores it in its DB and also sends it back to the client (using https, of course)
6. The AES-256 key is then stored by the app in the SharedPreferences using MODE_PRIVATE
7. All further communication between the app and the server is done over http:// with encrypted (payload (json/xml) + timestamp + checksum/hash) (CBC with random IV)
8. The AES key is only updated if the user changes his password
9. For actions that require additional security, the app asks the user to re-enter his password which is verified against the stored hash
10. The app should be usable offline (It can talk to pre-registered embedded devices over a WiFi connection. Security over WiFi is another story!)

I know some of the pitfalls of the system already:

1. Storing the key on the phone isn't safe: If a hacker gets access to the user's phone, the user just needs to change his password and everything will be safe.
2. Storing keys on the server is bad: A lot of people seem to say if you really have to store the keys, at least store them on a separate server. But that adds an extra round trip between the servers for every REST call. And there can potentially be many of them when the app is polling.
3. Keys without expiry are bad: I can't think of another way to let the app function offline.

The real questions now are:

1. What are the other loopholes that I've missed so far?
2. What kind of effort would it take for someone to break into the system?
3. Most important of all, how can we improve overall security to some "reasonable" standard without overdoing it?

Comment: If you were going to get a heart transplant would you go to a doctor with "close to zero experience"? The same applies to security, consider using a security domain expert.

Comment: Ask yourself why every single service out there is moving toward HTTPS and OAuth. The overhead of HTTPS was a legitimate concern in 1996, but it's trivial today.

Comment: The problem with OAUTH is trusting the 3rd parties authentication security. Maybe they allow "password" as a password and you do not feel that is adequate. It is necessary to examine the 3rd party's authentication security level and ensure it meets your needs.

Comment: @zaph - I agree. But in this case I'm the doctor and I'm not giving up my job because I don't have experience with this.

Comment: I use domain experts without giving up my job. Security is difficult to get correct. In most software a bug is usually just annoying, a bug in security software may let an attacker bypass the security.

Comment: Well, I've been asked to do something and I'm trying to find the most "reasonable" way to do it. "Hire someone else" is not what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Kulki Did they ask for working security or just a best attempt? I have had to fight to get security reviews and yes it will cost several thousand dollars. It was easier after the public security failure by my bosses code. So, this all comes down to wether we software developers are professionals because professionals have standards they follow and know their limits. Even having my roof replaced there are several reviews required by law including one that is destructive and requires repair after it is done.

Comment: The data isn't banking information and I don't think hiring a domain expert is on the cards. So it boils down to what we can do best.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** DoD security!

You really do need to use https and insure it is setup for TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy. Additionally the app needs to pin the certificate.

Section 1:

3: Do not use SHA256, use PBKDF2, crypt of another hash that has an increased work factor.

4: Send the password, not the hashed password to the server, the server does the hashing.

7: When using https there is no need to encrypt the payload, that is what https does.

Section 2:

2: When storing keys on the server keep them out of any http accessible directory. This is a weak point and needs to be addresses with server security.

Section 3:

Use two factor authentication for administration of the server. Have a good scheme to control the 2nd factor, I like hardware tokens and keep track of them by their serial numbers. That way there is a limited number and they can be recovered when someone is no longer should have administrator access. They can also be loaned for short periods of time.

You also need to have disaster plans for various contingencies, do not wait for an incidence and try to deal with it on the fly. Some times appropriate immediate action is required.

All of this is basic.

You need to evaluate potential threats, attackers and the value to an attacker or user.

If you care about security and are not a domain expert hire one for advice and review, I do.

Aside: DoD security: Two guard stations, two overhead passages between buildings, the last building has one door that is a huge safe door and there are no windows. Ceiling bubblegum lights rotating when there are un-cleared personal in the building, one escort per un-cleared person who follows you everywhere including into the bathroom, multiple sensors in the ceiling, tempest shielding.